# JavaScript Syntax empty {}

Tags: javascript, function, literals

I'm trying to figure out what does the empty `{}` mean.

```
var $sb = $sb || {};
```

Does this mean that varaible $sb's value is either copied to itself or it is a function literal?

full context:

```
var $sb = $sb || {};
$sb.xxx = function() {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var a = {}` is called the object literal notation. It's a faster than `var a = new Object()` because it needs no scope resolution (ie you could have defined a constructor with the same name and therefor the JavaScript engine must do such a lookup).

The pattern `var a = a || {};` is used to avoid replacing `a` in case you have already defined `a`. In this pattern, the or-operator: `||` functions as a coalescing operator. If `a` is `null` or `undefined` it will execute the expression at the right-hand of the statement: `{}`

Using this pattern ensures you that `a` will always be defined as an `object` and, in case it already exist, will not be overwritten.

Answer (score 5):

It's shortcut for

```
new Object()
```

So this line

```
var $sb = $sb || {};
```

Will check if variable `$sb` exists and if not create new object and assign it to `$sb` variable.

So in other way you can write this like:

```
if( !$sb ) {
    var $sb = new Object();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an object literal. Like:

```
var obj = { x: 4, y: 2 };
```

only there are no properties:

```
var obj = {};
```

The `||` operator returns the first operand if it evaluates to a non-falsy value, otherwise it returns the second operand. So the expression `$sb || {};` returns the value of `$sb` if it exists, otherwise it creates a new empty object.

Answer (score 1):

It is the abbreviation for `new Object()`

Answer (score 1):

It's short for:

```
new Object()
```

In this case, this means `$sb` will be set to it's own value, or to a new, empy object in case `$sb` is `undefined`.